# TemplateSyntaxError with static django 2

Tags: python, html, django

I have this code:

HTML

```
{% load static %}
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{% static game_reviews/css/ie/html5shiv.js %}"></script><![endif]-->
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'game_reviews',]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

i had a folder inside my app called static/game_reviews, and inside have multiple folder (js, css, etc.).

and i getting this error :

TemplateSyntaxError at /game_reviews/

Could not parse the remainder: '/css/ie/html5shiv.js' from 'game_reviews/css/ie/html5shiv.js'

Any help?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by the [django static-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/), you should send path as parameter:

```
{% load static %}
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{% static "game_reviews/css/ie/html5shiv.js" %}"></script><![endif]-->
                                    <!-- ^^                                ^^-->
```

Comment: Thanks!, i can'y find this anywhere, and was so simple. i had to review my css but at least the files are loading properly.

Comment: glad to help you!